# Any form of Update not working

Tags: apt

This is the message I get from command line trying to do update

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ mantic: /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key != /usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

After failed wine install.  The Ubuntu apps simply won't start.  Looked at other questions/answers, but none work. Any help would be appreciated and of course If additional information needed just ask.  Thanks!

Comment: Something is wrong with your sources list. Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` for any files or lines relating to your attempt to install wine.